# Can a gRPC client connect timeout be set independent of reconnect backoff settings?

Tags: grpc

We'd like to configure our gRPC client to reconnect very quickly after a connection is lost. (I believe the [default behavior](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/a3d4a200edf45ddc997d3f889ff298129b94aeb4/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.c#L48-L52) is to attempt to reconnect after 20 seconds, backing off to 120 seconds between attempts.) After a review of [available settings](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/a3d4a200edf45ddc997d3f889ff298129b94aeb4/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h#L236-L242), we tried setting `grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms` and `grpc.min_reconnect_backoff_ms` to 200. While that results in quick reconnects when a connection is lost, we sometimes see calls (from tests) fail with `GRPC::Internal: 13:Completed without a response`. Looking at logging from a tcp reverse proxy sitting between client and server, I see a connection lasting for just over 200ms, then a second connection lasting for longer. So it looks like the reconnect times are effectively serving as timeouts on connection attempts.

Is it possible to configure a gRPC client so that it will *begin attempting a reconnect* very quickly after a connection is lost, but allow creation of that connection to take longer than the reconnect time?

If it matters, this is a Ruby client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial backoff is *supposed* to be [1 second](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/connection-backoff.md).

You're experiencing [a bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12867) were the minimum connection timeout acts as both the timeout and the backoff (so the 1s initial backoff is ignored). So both your initial problem and the failed workaround are caused by the same bug.

(The bug was noticed a month ago, but an issue wasn't filed due to a mixup with a second bug. Your question here let me notice the missing issue.)

Comment: So the answer is "Not right now, but once [this bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12867) is fixed." Thanks.